# Ошибка list indices must be integers or slices, not str, не работает код. Помогите плиз!

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.x

```
vowels = ['a','e','i','o','u']
word = input("Provide a word to search for vowels: ")
found = []
for letter in word:
    if letter in vowels:
        if letter not in found:
            found.append(letter)
for vowel in found:
    print (vowel)


for k in found:
    print(k, 'was found', found[k], 'time(s).')
```

Comment: список `found` содержит строковые значения,  а Вы в последнем цикле, пытаетесь использовать их как индексы элементов этого-же списка. Какова цель программы?

Comment: Нужно посчитать сколько символом из масива повторяется

Comment: Ответ посмотрите, добавил вариант решения

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for k in found:
    print(k, 'was found', word.count(k), 'time(s).')
```

Comment: @MaxU какое решение (предложенное ранее?) вы имеете ввиду?

Comment: Пардон, не заметил отличия

Answer (score 1):

Если я правильно понял задачу, то Ваш код должен выглядеть примерно так:

```
vowels = ['a','e','i','o','u']
word = input("Provide a word to search for vowels: ")
found = []
for letter in word:
    if letter in vowels:
        if letter not in found:
            found.append(letter)
for vowel in found:
    print (vowel)


for k in found:
    print(k, 'was found', found.count(k), 'time(s).')
```

Но на мой взгляд более практичным решением будет следующее:

```
vowels = ['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u']
word = input("Provide a word to search for vowels: ")
for let in vowels:
    if let in word:
        print(f'{let} was found {word.count(let)} time(s)')
```